# Can I find a Java function names/syntax in Notepad++ or JRE/JDK folder?

Tags: java, notepad++

Actually, I have my practical Java exam tomorrow.

Only notepad++ is allowed in the exam, sometimes I forget the name of functions or I want to search for functions to do a specific task.

In notepad++ can I find all function names or anything that might help me in my exam?

Are the functions stored somewhere inside notepad++ folder or in settings or inside JRE/JDK folder? Maybe, any offline documentation when we install java?

Comment: No, no browsing for still unused method names. One can install the JDK's javadoc (huge, so maybe better in a compressed (zip) folder) and use a browser (menubar Launch in browser). If that is okay. Inform others too. (=share any blame)

Comment: nope , you can't find , but you can leverage  notepad++  to check the program and compile it using notepad ++ , assuming you have java class path on the machine you are using notepad++ ,follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J83DFnEe_Uc&app=desktop

Comment: If you don't have any javadoc file, you can get the information from the rt.jar under the jre/lib directory.The javap command with -public option will show you a signature of a class and method you take. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javap.html